# Get the custom post type slug but remove the rewrite prefix?

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, slug

I am trying to add a link to the parent custom post archive page in the breadcrumbs. I can get the slug using this:

```
<?php
$post_type = get_post_type();
if ( $post_type )
{
$post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
$post_type_slug = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
echo $post_type_slug;
}
?>
```

Now then... my custom post types have a custom rewrite slug to add news into the URL:

news/events
news/awards

etc..

I need to get the slug without the rewrite news/ because I already have the 'news' in the breadcrumbs.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Got it working with the help of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097900/remove-part-of-a-url-with-php

Comment: <?php
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ( $post_type )
    {
        $post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
        $post_type_slug = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
     $remove = "/news";
        echo $post_type_slug = substr($post_type_slug, strlen($remove));
    }
   ?>